# Объединить таблицы, совместив по ключу. PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Таблица 1 имеет такие поля: `id, compare_filed, field_1`

Таблица 2 имеет такие поля: `id, compare_filed, field_2`

Нужно объединить таблицы так, чтобы сохранились записи из обоих, НО совместились по полю `compare_filed`. Если нет вхождения у какой-либо таблицы, заполняем пустотой.

Для примера таблица 1 (`t1`) имеет такое содержимое:

```
----------------------------------------
 id  |  compare_filed  |  field_1
 1   |  100            |  value_1
 2   |  200            |  value_2
 3   |  300            |  value_3
 4   |  444            |  value_4
 5   |  555            |  value_5
```

Таблица 2 (`t2`):

```
----------------------------------------
 id  |  compare_filed  |  field_2
 11  |  100            |  value_11
 12  |  200            |  value_12
 13  |  300            |  value_13
 14  |  123            |  value_14
 15  |  456            |  value_15
```

После объединения должно получится вот так:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 t1.id  |  t1.compare_filed  |  t1.field_2  |  t2.id  |  t2.compare_filed  |  t2.field_2
 1      |  100               |  value_1     |  11     |  100               |  value_11
 2      |  200               |  value_2     |  12     |  200               |  value_12
 3      |  300               |  value_3     |  13     |  300               |  value_13
 4      |  444               |  value_4     |  NULL   |  NULL              |  NULL
 5      |  555               |  value_5     |  NULL   |  NULL              |  NULL
 NULL   |  NULL*             |  NULL        |  14     |  123*              |  value_14
 NULL   |  NULL*             |  NULL        |  15     |  456*              |  value_15
```

`NULL*` - в дополнение, возможно ли эти NULL заменить на значения `t2.compare_filed`?

Comment: почитайте `full join`

Comment: `coalesce`, `ISNULL`, `IFNULL` что там из этого есть в psql ?

Comment: разобрался с full join и с coalesce